# Unit testing does not fail when I add 1 to the variables to be equated to

Tags: testing, mocha

Just started with unit testing after creating my token, but the test cases are passing even if I add a number in the equals bracket.

In test one, if I change to `expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply+1);` then the test case  fails, but not when using `eventually`.

Doing the same as above for other test case, does not work, they simply fail even when correct.

What am I missing out?

```
contract("Token Test",async (accounts)=>{

    const[deployerAccount, recepient, anotherAccount]=accounts;

    it("one-all tokens should be in my account", async () => {
        let instance = await Token.deployed();
        let totalSupply =await instance.totalSupply();
        expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
    })

    it("two-is possible to send token between accounts", async () => {

        const sendTokens=1;
        let instance= await Token.deployed();
        let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply()+1;
        expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
        expect(instance.transfer(recepient, sendTokens)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
        expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply.sub(new BN(sendTokens)));
        expect(instance.balanceOf(recepient)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(new BN(sendTokens));
      
    })

    it("three-is not possible to send more tokens than available in total", async()=>{
        let instance=await Token.deployed();
        let balanceOfDeployer=await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
        expect(instance.transfer(recepient,new BN(balanceOfDeployer+1))).to.be.rejected;
        expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.bignumber.equal(balanceOfDeployer);
    })


});
```

Did I make sense? please help!

Comment: Never used the `eventually` myself, and not sure, but the documentation at https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/ uses  `should`. Maybe try that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a `before each()` function and replacing the instance.

```
contract("Token Test",async (accounts)=>{
    

    const[deployerAccount, recipient, anotherAccount]=accounts;

    beforeEach(async()=>{
        this.myToken=await Token.new(process.env.INITIAL_TOKENS);
    })

    it("all tokens should be in my account", async () => {
        let instance = this.myToken;
        let totalSupply =await instance.totalSupply();
        let balanceOfDeployer=await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
       // let balance=await instance.balanceOf(account[0]);
        // assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), initialSupply.valueOf(), "The balance was not the same");
        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
    })
    
    it("is possible to send token between accounts",async()=>{
        const sendTokens=1;
        let instance=this.myToken;
        let totalSupply =await instance.totalSupply();
        let balanceOfDeployer=await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
        // console.log("total",totalSupply);
        // console.log("balance",balanceOfDeployer);
        // console.log("token",sendTokens);
        expect(new BN(balanceOfDeployer)).to.be.a.bignumber.eql(totalSupply);
        await expect(instance.transfer(recipient, 1)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled; 
        await expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply.sub(new BN(sendTokens)));
        await expect(instance.balanceOf(recipient)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(new BN(sendTokens));
    })

    it("is not possible to send more tokens than available in total", async()=>{
        let instance=this.myToken;
        let balanceOfDeployer=await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
        expect(instance.transfer(recipient,new BN(balanceOfDeployer))).to.eventually.be.rejected;
        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(balanceOfDeployer);
    })
    
    
});
```